# Comparing dates with time zone

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have a piece of code as below.
Date beginDate;
Calendar endDate;
//begin date is from database (java.util.Date) not sql.date
// endDate is from request parameter
    // endTime is of type Calendar.getTimeInMillis()
    // beginTime is of type java.util.date.getTime()
    boolean isEndDateBeforeStartDate = endTime < beginTime ? true : false

For some specific cases I am getting end time is greater than begin time. This could be becase of time zone variations I guess. Can someone point me to the right way of comparing such dates with timezones considered.

Comment: Your question is *way* too vague to answer. We have no idea where the values come from, what time zones are involved, or what kind of comparison you're trying to make.

Comment: Additionally, `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` isn't a type - that may well be where you got the value from, but that's not the *type* of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the timezones then convert them to a common timezone then compare.